# Multiple long orders with separate take profit and stop loss

Tags: position, pine-script, long-integer, loss

A bit new with coding. Hope to find some help.

I am trying to get each long position to have its own take profit and stop loss.
What ends up happening is, whenever the next long position is triggered, the previous TP and SL get recalculated and I end up with all positions having only one TP and SL levels.
Thanks
Played around with exit code and lastEntryPriceLong but not a big coder, soo... any help would be appreciated.

```
//////// Long Position 0 (1) ////////

if longCondition and longConditionATR and longConditionEMA and barRangeCondition and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)

lastEntryPriceLong = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)

var float LongTP = na
var float LongSL = na

if (strategy.position_size[1] != strategy.position_size)
    LongTP := lastEntryPriceLong*2 - low[1]
    LongSL := lastEntryPriceLong - (lastEntryPriceLong - low[1] + atr*2)

inTradeLong = strategy.position_size > 0

plot(inTradeLong ? LongTP : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(inTradeLong ? LongSL : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles)

strategy.exit('Close Long', 'Long', stop=LongSL, limit=LongTP)


//////// Long Position 1 (2) ////////

if longCondition and longConditionATR and longConditionEMA and barRangeCondition and strategy.opentrades == 1
    strategy.entry('Long1', strategy.long)

lastEntryPriceLong1 = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1)

var float LongTP1 = na
var float LongSL1 = na

if (strategy.position_size[1] != strategy.position_size)
    LongTP1 := lastEntryPriceLong1*2 - low[1]
    LongSL1 := lastEntryPriceLong1 - (lastEntryPriceLong1 - low[1] + atr*2)

inTradeLong1 = strategy.position_size > 0

plot(inTradeLong1 ? LongTP1 : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(inTradeLong1 ? LongSL1 : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles)

strategy.exit('Close Long1', 'Long1', stop=LongSL1, limit=LongTP1)
```

[You can see Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzwXK.png)

Thanks

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strategy.exit` is in the root scope. So, it gets executed on each bar overwriting earlier entry.

You need to do few things here:

1. Move `strategy.exit` and the related calculations inside if condition where you have `strategy.entry`. This way, exit and entry are set together.
2. Use an auto incrementing Id instead of same id for all. You can do it using

> ```
> var id= 1
> if(longCondition)
>   entryId = Long+str.tostring(id)
>   exitId = ExitLong+str.tostring(id)
>   id+=1
>   strategy.entry(entryId, strategy.long, ...)
>   strategy.exit(exitId, entryId, ...)
> ```

3. In strategy definition, set `close_entry_rule` to `ANY`. This will let each trade track it's own exit based on id instead of closing order based on FIFO or FILO.
   https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you
The only thing I could not manage was to plot the TP and SL levels.
inTradeLong = strategy.position_size > 0
plot(inTradeLong ? LongTP : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(inTradeLong ? LongSL : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles)
(This probably has to be edited because it was the old setup, but the errors seem to be of another nature)
When inside the "if" condition, it said "cannot use 'plot' in a local scope". 
When outside the "if" condition - mismatched input 'plot' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'